# How to define the configuration for AWS DynamoDB in .Net 4 and C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using DynamoDB, where "User" is the Table and Model Object name. I get this error:

```
Requested resource not found: Table: User not found
```

web.config settings are as below.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="AWSAccessKey" value="asdf" />
    <add key="AWSSecretKey" value="Vi+asdfsecretImnottelling" />
</appSettings>
```

I'm currently using my localhost to debug my application. Is this allowed?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't set the `ServiceURL` which is a problem as I'm not using the default region.

By default, AWS SDK for .NET sets the endpoint to

```
https://dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

You can also set the endpoint explicitly as shown in this C# code snippet:

```
private static void CreateClient()
{
    AmazonDynamoDBConfig config = new AmazonDynamoDBConfig();
    config.ServiceURL = "http://dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com";
    client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(config);
}
```

Amazon's "[What Is Amazon DynamoDB?](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/TestingDotNetApiSamples.html)" will help too.

Comment: Instead of defining the endpoint URL,   you can use following code to create the client for AmazonDynamoDBClient. 

AmazonDynamoDBClient client  = new  AmazonDynamoDBClient(“your id”,” your key”, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.US.east1);

Answer (score 0):

Create user by using IAM, it is a AWS service. Then do the following configuration in your app settings according to the user you have added:

```
"AWS": {
"Profile": "",
"AccessKey": "",
"SecretKey": "",
"Region": ""}
```

The following method is easy to create DynamoDb client with basic credential:

```
AmazonDynamoDBClient awsDbClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(strAccessKey, strSecretKey, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(strRegion));
```

For aws DB access library you can visit this link: https://github.com/MeghnathDas/DynamoDbPlugin

Comment: Rather than toss out code, please explain _why_ it's the correct solution. Our goal is to help educate in addition to solve the problem so the OP understands how to fix the problem in the future too.